# Почему binding возвращает object.ToString(), а не привязанное значение combobox-a?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

**ViewModel**

```
_events = new Dictionary<string, string>()
{
    { "allEvents", "All" },
    { "concerts", "Concerts" },
    { "sports", "Sports" },
    { "arts-theater", "Art & Theater" },
    { "family", "Family" }
};

public Dictionary<string, string> Events
{
    get
    {
        return _events;
    }
}

public string SelectedEvent
{
    get { return _selectedEvent; }
    set
    {
        _selectedEvent = value;
        RaisePropertyChangedEvent("SelectedEvent");
    }
}
```

**Window.xaml**

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Events}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEvent}" SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

После выбора, например `{ "sports", "Sports" }`, в SelectedEvent `value` приходит со значением `[sports, Sport]`, а мне нужен только `Key` выбранного объекта, а не сам item. И вроде бы указала, чтобы возвращало `Key` (`SelectedValuePath="Key"`). Или это нужно не так делать? Сам `value` не позволяет явно преобразовать себя в `KeyValuePair<string, string>`. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании `SelectedItem` вы привязываете полностью весь объект к свойству (из за привязки к `string` свойству вам и пытаются сделать `.toString` для этого объекта), `SelectedValuePath` не как на него не влияет, оно влияет на `SelectedValue`.

Так что просто замените `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEvent}"` на `SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedEvent}"`. Либо меняйте у свойства тип `string` на то, что у вас храниться в привязанной коллекции (в вашем случае это `KeyValuePair<string, string>`).